# How to get key value in this case {Java Script}

Tags: javascript

Hi so what iam trying to achieve is basically is simple.Iam try to get only the object key's value from the given array
so this is my example array

`[{'aaa': '11','text':'hello'},{'aaa': '12','text':'bye'}]`
iam expecting a output of something like this
[11,12]

where iam getting the data of the aaa key only

Comment: There is no concept of "the first key` - it could change based on javascript implementations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want, but the order could well change between different javascript implementations

```js
const input = [{'aaa': '11','text':'hello'},{'bbb': '12','text':'bye'}]

const output = input.map(x => Object.values(x)[0]);

console.log(output)
```

---

I note you updated the quesrtion to have both the same first key - if you're looking for `aaa` value from all elements this is much simpler

```js
const input = [{'aaa': '11','text':'hello'},{'aaa': '12','text':'bye'}]

const output = input.map(x => x.aaa);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const o = [{'aaa': '11','text':'hello'},{'aaa': '12','text':'bye'}]

const filtered = o.map(i => +i.aaa)
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: thanks this solved my questions.however iam open to any other better ways of it doing it too

Comment: what do you mean with "other better ways" ??

Comment: anything faster in terms of performance

Answer (score -1):

The JSON path if you convert this into a JavaScript Object Notation format (as JSON).

0.aaa  = 11

1.bbb  = 12